# How to access request.FILES from django admin form submission?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-admin

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=Document, dispatch_uid='question_save_signal')
def log_save_question(sender, instance, using, **kwargs):
    p = instance
```

Here is the code I use to intercept saving in django admin. From inside this function, I would need to access request.FILES to access new files that were just selected in an ImageField and are being submitted.
How would you do it ?

Comment: Have you checked whether the file is available via the appropriate instance attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a pre_save function, the properties are already set to the object, however it is not saved to the db yet.
So if your Document Model has an attribute `image`, you should be able to access it through: `instance.image`

Comment: You are right. It's just that the meta properties of the files itself are not the same as when passed from the frontend... thus it caused some errors, but it was not about the physical file itself.